# Highcharts stacking bar chart border not displaying on right side

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When I create a stacking bar chart, the rightmost 'box' doesn't have the border drawn on the right hand side.

Is there an option or something that I can set in [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) to force the white border line to be drawn around the 75% box in the image seen below?

Here is a link to the jsfiddle I used for testing:
http://jsfiddle.net/zKgsF/

[image: Image of the problem]

Please note: Setting the borderWidth property to higher than 1 works in displaying, but the rightmost border is much thinner than the others. See the image below.

[image: borderWidth to 5]

Here is the javascript for the chart:

```
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'bar',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,.3)',
            margin: [15,6,15,15],
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['']
        },
        credits: {
          enabled: false
        },
        yAxis: {
          gridLineColor: "#FF0000",
          labels: 
          {
            align: 'right',
            formatter: function()
            {
              return this.value + "%";
            }
                },
        },
        tooltip: {
                formatter: function() 
          {
                        return "<b>" + this.series.name + '</b>: ' + this.y + ' (' +            Math.round(this.percentage,1) + "%)";
                }
            },
        plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                    animation: false,
                    stacking: 'percent',
                    borderWidth: '1',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: 'white',
                        formatter: function() {

                            if (this.percentage < 10) 
                            {
                                return ""
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return Math.round(this.percentage,1) + "%";
                            }
                        },
                        style: {
                            fontSize: '18px'
                        }

                    }
                }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [30]        
        },{
            data: [10]        
        }]
    });
});
```

EDIT:

Looks like it's not related to the bar chart being "stackable". It might just be related to the fact that the chart goes to the max 'y' value axis... as seen here in another example: http://jsfiddle.net/zKgsF/1/

Comment: Can't figure out how to do it, but you can use a trick if it helps you. Set the max value of yAxis to 101, and put a condition for not printing yValues larger than 100 in labels.formatter option. Take a look at the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zKgsF/23/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by [Cubbuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1045081/cubbuk), you can tweak it with by adding the `max` value of yAxis.

In addition, you can specify a `endOnTick` property too.

```
 max: 100.1,
 endOnTick: false
```

For API navigate [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.endOnTick) and for here is an **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/gopinaghr/zKgsF/26/).**